# return statement not stopping code java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to check whether a word is a palindrome, i am using recursion, i don't know what i am doing wrong but when i reach the base case the method keeps on calling eventually all word return false. Can anyone help me find the error? thank you :/

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String isPalindrome = sc.next();
    String regex = "[.!? ]";
    isPalindrome.split(regex);
    if(testPalindrome(isPalindrome)==true)
    {
        System.out.print(isPalindrome+" is a palindrome.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(isPalindrome+" is not a palindrome.");
    }
}
public static boolean testPalindrome(String word)
{
    if(word.charAt(0)==word.charAt(word.length()-1))
    {
        if(word.length()==1)
        {
            return true;
        }
            word = word.substring(1, (word.length()-1));
            testPalindrome(word);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the result of the recursive call. Right now, you call the function recursively yes, but ultimately, since you don't return from the function when you make the recursive call, the flow of execution leaves that outer `if` statement and moves to `return false;` even if you recurse and the recursion somewhere down the line returns `true`.

```
public static boolean testPalindrome(String word)
{
    if(word.charAt(0)==word.charAt(word.length()-1))
    {
        if(word.length()==1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        word = word.substring(1, (word.length()-1));
        return testPalindrome(word);
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: superhawk610 is also right about your exit condition. It will only be valid for an odd number of characters in the string. You should probably use something like `if (word.length() <= 1)` instead to catch both odd and even cases. Which means final code would be:

```
public static boolean testPalindrome(String word)
{
    if(word.charAt(0)==word.charAt(word.length()-1))
    {
        if(word.length()<=1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        word = word.substring(1, (word.length()-1));
        return testPalindrome(word);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: :| How did i miss that? :/ Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it will work with words with an odd length but not words with an even length. Change your test statement from

```
if(word.length() == 1)
```

to

```
if(word.length() < 2)
```

This will end recursion if you've trimmed down to 1 character (the middle of an odd length word) or 0 (the "middle" of an even length word).

Answer (score 0):

suppose you do not need to check for `true` in the if as the method returns a `boolean`

```
System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String isPalindrome = sc.next();
        String regex = "[.!? ]";
        isPalindrome.split(regex);
        if(testPalindrome(isPalindrome))
        {
            System.out.print(isPalindrome+" is a palindrome.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(isPalindrome+" is not a palindrome.");
        }
```

also `testPalindrome()` method should be like this to work in recursion.

```
public static boolean testPalindrome(String word)
{
    if(word.charAt(0)==word.charAt(word.length()-1))
    {
        if(word.length()==1)
        {
            return true;
        }
            word = word.substring(1, (word.length()-1));
            return testPalindrome(word);
    }
    return false;
}
```